# How to update flutter firestore database with conditions using alert dialog box?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try to update todo update data no problem but I will try when Click update button then show current data that insert first time.Please give any idea how can I this?
I want to make update one parameter but it's update all data null value

```
editTodo(BuildContext context, List<Todo> todos, String todoId) {
  var todoEditProvider = Provider.of<TodoView>(context);
  showDialog(context: context,builder: (BuildContext context){
    return AlertDialog(
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(child: Text("Cancel"),onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context);},),
        FlatButton(child: Text("Update"),onPressed: (){
          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            _formKey.currentState.save();
            todoEditProvider.updateTodo(Todo(uId:"uId",subject: editTodoValue,completed: true,status: false,cUpdate: DateTime.now().toString()) ,todoId);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
        },),
      ],
      content: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _tEditTEC,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: todos[0].subject,
                ),
                validator: (String value){
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please Enter Todo';
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (value) => editTodoValue = value,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Is the problem with the `updateTodo` function? I don't understand exactly what is the problem :(

Comment: I want when I update data form that time show current data.

Comment: Could you post the `updateTodo` as well?

Comment: yes https://prnt.sc/qro3qk

Comment: No I mean the `todoEditProvider.updateTodo`

Comment: I give link please see

Comment: updateTodo function is ok

Comment: Future updateTodo(Todo data, String id) async {
    await _todoApi.updateDocument(id, data.toJson());
    return;
  }

Comment: Future<void> updateDocument(String id,Map data){
    return todoReferance.document(id).updateData(data);
  }

Comment: Well it seems that in updateTodo (that I suppose it's inside a Provider) it's missing the `notifyListeners()` method